# Unable to read from user in rpm install script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat, rpmbuild

I've Created RPM Package which contains shell script code which shown     below. When I'm installing it in RedHat OS, It is not taking user input and continuously looping. If I run the same file manually it's working fine. If Anybody Knows Please let me know.

```
set +e 

IpAddress='0' 
condition=1    

while [[ $condition -ne 0 ]] 
do
    echo ' '   
    echo "PLEASE PROVIDE APPLIANCE IP" 
    read IpAddress   
    if valid_ip $IpAddress;   
    then
       condition=0   
    else
    echo $IpAddress  " IS INVALID IP PLEASE PROVIDE A VALID IP: " 
    echo ' '
    condition=1   
    f`enter code here`i 
done

condition=1 
while [[ $condition -ne 0 ]] 
do   
     echo "PLEASE PROVIDE APPLIANCE LOGIN PASSWORD"   
     read uiPassword   
     echo "The Password u entered is "$uiPassword   
     echo "Press Yes/No:"   
     read choice  
     choice=`echo $choice | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`   
    case "$choice" in   
     yes|Yes ) condition=0;;   
     no|No ) echo "no";;   
     * ) echo "invalid";; 
    esac 
done

set -e
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

It's intentional that you can't; RPMs shouldn't prompt for user input, and for that reason, RPM closes stdin before running hook scripts.

However, if you want to try harder (which you shouldn't!), then open `/dev/tty` to find the process attached to your controlling TTY:

```
if exec </dev/tty; then
  read IpAddress || {
    : "deal with the case where attempting to read from the user failed here"
  }
  # ...and use the information read here...
else
  : "deal with the case where you simply can't read from the user here"
fi
```

---

Best practice when software needs information before it can work is to require that information to be written to a configuration file out-of-band.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked for details on handling user input on RPM installation scripts and the widest consensus I can find is that you should not try to get user input.

Typical rationale is the case of installing RPMs from a graphical UI, as described [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s04s05.html).

Also, I found this related question where the "no" answer also appears: https://superuser.com/questions/408852/is-it-possible-to-get-users-input-during-installation-of-rpm

Comment: "No" is incorrect, in a technical-pedant sense. It's the best answer, inasmuch as folks should find a better way to configure the software they're installing, but that doesn't make it an accurate answer to a question that starts with "is it possible".